# Sencha application deploy

Tags: extjs

I have a JSP with Sencha grid (filtering and sorting columns).
After deploy I have an app-all.js file with size 550KB !

Is it possible ? 550KB only for grid ?

Thanks

Comment: It also comes with minified version for that file.

Comment: Yes minified, is it possible or I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal with Sencha. You can save some space by editing the CSS template files(SCSS files) and re-generating the CSS work files from the template, but it won't save you much space (10-20%, probably not much more).
I've tried removing actual functionality from Sencha (functionality that I didn't need): some files that were removed were not worth the trouble and other files that were removed just broke Sencha.

So, yes, sadly that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. Grid panels have a long list of dependencies that need to be included. Just for example, it extends from Ext.Panel, which uses the Ext.Draw package for certain functionalities in IE6+ (like vertical text). Then there is the whole Class system, MVC, etc that gets involved.